# Rails - Unable to save a form to sqlite db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form that I'm trying to save to my database. Unfortunately I can't figure out why it is not saving. If I call .save explicitly it just rollback it:

[image]

Controller in which I'm persisting the data:

```
def create
    @new_request = Bug.new(params.require(:bug).permit(:project_id, :title, :assignee_id, :status,
                                                       :description, :creator_id, :deadline, :bug_type))
    @new_request.project_id = $project_id
    @new_request.creator_id = current_user.id
    @new_request.assignee_id = 0
    @new_request.status = 0
    @new_request.save
    byebug
    redirect_to new_qa_path(type: @type)
  end
```

This data is passed from the view form:

```
<%= form_with scope: :bug, url: qa_index_path, local: true do |form| %>
    <p>
      <%= form.label :project_title %><br>
      <%= form.text_field :project_title, value: @project, disabled: true%>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= form.label :title %><br>
      <%= form.text_field :title%>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= form.label :description %><br>
      <%= form.text_field :description %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= form.label :bug_type %><br/>
      <%= form.select(:bug_type, Bug::bug_types.map{|k,v| [k]})%>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= form.label :status %><br>
      <%= form.text_field :status, value: 'New', disabled: true %><br>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= form.label :deadline %><br>
      <%= form.date_select :deadline, start_year: Time.now.year, end_year: Time.now.year + 3%>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= form.submit %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
```

My schema:

```
 create_table "bugs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "project_id"
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "assignee_id"
    t.integer "status"
    t.string "description"
    t.integer "creator_id"
    t.date "deadline"
    t.integer "bug_type"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

bug.rb Model:

```
class Bug < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project, foreign_key: true
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true

  enum bug_type: { Bug: 0, Feature: 1 }
  enum status: { New: 0, Started: 1, Completed: 2, Resolved: 3 }
end
```

I'm very new to rails so any help will be much appreciated. Thank You!

**Update 1**
[image]

I checked both the tables they do contain the user and project as well.

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Project id: 20, title: "BMW China", manager_id: 7, created_at: "2022-02-11 12:11:16", updated_at: "2022-02-11 12:11:16">

#<User id: 12, email: "someone@example.com", username: "qa", created_at: "2022-02-12 10:24:54", updated_at: "2022-02-12 10:24:54", user_type: "Quality_Assurance", firstname: "Faraz", lastname: "Rafiq">]>
```

**Update-2**

I updated my models so that in case I'm using custom id names, I need to properly define the foreign key relations. This is my attempt:

User Model (User.rb):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  enum user_type: { Manager: 0, Developer: 1, Quality_Assurance: 2 }

  has_many :projects, inverse_of: :manager
  has_many :bugs, inverse_of: :assignee
end
```

Project Model (project.rb)

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: :User, foreign_key: :manager_id
  has_many :bugs, inverse_of: :project
end
```

Bug Model (bug.rb)

```
class Bug < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project, class_name: :Project, foreign_key: :project_id
  belongs_to :assignee, class_name: :User, foreign_key: :assignee_id
  # belongs_to :project, foreign_key: true
  # belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true

  enum bug_type: { Bug: 0, Feature: 1 }
  enum status: { New: 0, Started: 1, Completed: 2, Resolved: 3 }
end
```

Unfortunately, @new_project.errors still give the following error when I try to save a new bug:

```
(byebug) @new_request.errors
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007fc9990eeb28 @base=#<Bug id: nil, project_id: 21, title: "A new bug", assignee_id: 0, status: "New", description: "My bug", creator_id: 12, deadline: "2022-02-12", bug_type: "Bug", created_at: "2022-02-12 19:05:09", updated_at: "2022-02-12 19:05:09">, @messages={:assignee=>["must exist"]}, @details={:assignee=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

Comment: I'd like o see your Bug model please. Probably some validation is failing. Have you tried to do @new_request.errors in your byebug debug console?

Comment: Yes I do have foreign_keys defined in this table. There are two foreign keys coming from table projects and users. I'm using Rails 5.2 but there is no tag defined for them. I updated the tags now.

Comment: What's this assignment: `@new_request.project_id = $project_id` ? I don't recognize the $ in front of project_id. Shouldn't project_id come from the parameters you call in the first line in your method?

Comment: I updated the post, please have a look at the error. @new_request.project_id = $project_id is just assinging the project_id (a global variable) to the column project_id.

Comment: You have a `belongs_to :user` association defined in your model. But you do not assign in user a `user_id` in the controller. Instead, you assign a `creator_id` but there is no `belongs_to :creator` in the model. And then there is a `assignee_id ` in the table but no matching association in the model.

Comment: I’m sorry I think didn’t get your point entirely. Actually the creator_id and assignee_id are the same as user_id. They have been given a different name just for clarity. Can you please point a code snippet that can fox this?

Comment: You cannot define a `belongs_to :user` association in your model and expect Rails to understand, that it needs to use the `creator_id` to `assignee_id` to handle it. You have to follow Rails' naming conventions or have to explicitly tell Rails that the association needs to use a different database column as expected. I suggest reading in the Rails Guides about [Association Basics, `belongs_to`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference).

Comment: @spickermann I read that guide you attached and based on that I properly tried to define foreign key relations. My attempt is attached in Update 2, please have a look. Can you help me spot the mistake I'm making now?

Comment: The changes you did to the associations are great but you assign `@new_request.assignee_id = 0` in the controller and there certainly doesn't exist an assignee (user) with the ID `0` in the database. You need to assign an assignee (user) that actually exists.

Comment: I assigned assignee id = 0 initially because the bugs has just been created and is not assigned to anyone yet. On the developers screen I'm assinging this to the developer.

Comment: The error message is quite clear `@messages={:assignee=>["must exist"]}, @details={:assignee=>[{:error=>:blank}]}` you do not assign an existing assignee.

Comment: You may just need to make your assignee optional: `belongs_to :assignee, class_name: :User, foreign_key: :assignee_id, optional: true`